# iOS 7: What frame is self.view.frame?

Tags: ios, view, hierarchy

I'm starting to get confused in the whole frame calculation. I cannot say for sure since I don't know the exact sizes of the iphone screen, but I think in my app self.view.frame results in a wrong value (480 on a 3.5 inch screen). I guess this frame includes status-,nav- and tabbar? Does it always include that? Because I have actually deselected all "Exend edges ..." in interface builder.

And how do you get then the screen size without nav and tabbar?

And let's say self.frame does return the complete screen size including all the bars. I have this line of code in my app to return the frame position of an embedded tableview in relation to the super view:

```
self.tableView.tableFrameInMainView = [self.centerView convertRect:self.tableView.frame toView:self.view];
```

And this one works. This one returns exactly the same value as all the constraints sum up to set in interface builder for this tableview, compared to the y=0 value of my screen (my screen below the navigation bar).

That's why I'm confused...how can this one return a value without the navigation bar and the self.view.frame.size.height return a value with all the bars?

Answer (score 1):

check out the `UIWindow` property that all `UIView`'s have...

`CGRect fullRect = self.view.window.frame;`